# PowerBi Embedded report.getFilters() - convert promise to syncronous

Tags: javascript, promise, powerbi-embedded

My page uses PowerBi embedded and I want to be able to return in javaScript the current filters in the report back to the server.

The call is easy enough, just call report.getFilters() in javaScript.
Unfortunately for me it returns a promise. How can I convert this to a syncronous call?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/report.report

Comment: Use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to handle the asynchronous property in JavaScript. I used one of them that is async/await.
It is used for writing asynchronous code in JavaScript to make code behave in a synchronous way.
The word async used before the function means it always returns a promise. If a function returns a non-promise value, the async function returns like a resolved promise. And await works only inside async function and it makes JavaScript wait until the promise settles and returns the result.

Code:

```js
async function getfilter() {

    const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
    report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

    // Get the filters on the report page
    const filter= await report.getFilters(); 
    console.log('The filters on the report is:', filter)
}
```

Output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K532I.png

you can also refer to-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/